# SAS Array Variable Name Based on Another Array

Tags: sas

I have data in the following format:

```
data have;
input id rtl_apples rtl_oranges rtl_berries;
    datalines;
1 50 60 10
2 10 30 80
3 40 8 1
;
```

I'm trying to create new variables that represent the percent of the sum of the RTL variables, `PCT_APPLES, PCT_ORANGES, PCT_BERRIES`. The problem is I'm doing this within a macro so the names and number of RTL variables with vary with each iteration so the new variable names need to be generated dynamically.

This data step essentially gets what I need, but the new variables are in the format `PCT1, PCT2, PCTn` format so it's difficult to know which RTL variable the PCT corresponds too.

```
data want;
set have;
array rtls[*] rtl_:;
total_sales = sum(of rtl_:);
call symput("dim",dim(rtls));
array pct[&dim.];
do i=1 to dim(rtls);
    pct[i] = rtls[i] / total_sales;
end;
drop i;
run;
```

I also tried creating the new variable name by using a macro variable, but only the last variable in the array is created. In this case, `PCT_BERRIES`.

```
data want;
set have;
array rtls[*] rtl_:;
total_sales = sum(of rtl_:);
do i=1 to dim(rtls);
    var_name = compress(tranwrd(upcase(vname(rtls[i])),'RTL','PCT'));
    call symput("var_name",var_name);
    &var_name. = rtls[i] / total_sales;
end;
drop i var_name;
run;
```

I have a feeling I'm over complicating this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the source of the existing names?  Are the PCT_BERRIES etc names being generated by a program?  Or are they just created by some external process that is not under your control?

Comment: The apples, oranges, berries are outside of my control, but I'm adding the RTL prefix like `proc transpose prefix=RTL_`

Comment: So you have the list in data already?  Just use that to make a macro variable with the list of names.

Comment: @Tom I just realized that as I was posting the comment. I was hoping to do it all within the data step but that's just as easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the list of names in data already then use the list to create the names you need for your arrays.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select distinct cats('RTL_',name),cats('PCT_',name)
  into :rtl_list separated by ' '
     , :pct_list separated by ' '
  from dataset_with_names
  ;
quit;

data want;
  set have;
  array rtls &rtl_list;
  array pcts &pct_list;
  total_sales = sum(of rtls[*]);
  do index=1 to dim(rtls);
    pcts[index] = rtls[index] / total_sales;
  end;
  drop index ;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't create variables while a data step is executing.  This program uses PROC TRANSPOSE to create a new data using the RTL_ variables "renamed" PCT_.

```
data have;
   input id rtl_apples rtl_oranges rtl_berries;
   datalines;
1 50 60 10
2 10 30 80
3 40 8 1
;;;;
   run;
proc transpose data=have(obs=0) out=names;
   var rtl_:;
   run;
data pct;
   set names;
   _name_ = transtrn(_name_,'rtl_','PCT_');
   y = .;
   run;
proc transpose data=pct out=pct2;
   id _name_;
   var y;
   run;
data want;
   set have;
   if 0 then set pct2(drop=_name_);
   array _rtl[*] rtl_:;
   array _pct[*] pct_:;
   call missing(of _pct[*]);
   total = sum(of _rtl[*]);
   do i = 1 to dim(_rtl);
      _pct[i] = _rtl[i]/total*1e2;
      end;
   drop i;
   run;

proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may want to just report the row percents

```
  proc transpose data=&data out=&data.T;
    by id;
    var rtl_:;
  run;

  proc tabulate data=&data.T;
    class id _name_;
    var col1;
    table 
      id=''
    , _name_='Result'*col1=''*sum=''
      _name_='Percent'*col1=''*rowpctsum=''
    / nocellmerge;
  run;
```

[image]